# Delete multiple rows with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I tried this piece of code :

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
("DELETE [MYSCHEMA].TABLE1 Where TABLE2.Id = 5");
```

But I get this exception : *Cannot call methods on nvarchar.*

Currently I use a loop but I'd like avoid this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
     ("DELETE [MYSCHEMA].TABLE1 Where TABLE2_Id = 5");
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete syntax is 'delete from TABLE where ...'

try `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM [MYSCHEMA].TABLE1 Where Table2.Id = 5");`